# how to make an animation like Explore Flickr app rotation animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, three20

I have an ipad app that has a page inside it subclassed from `TTThumbsViewController`( which is a class in the `Three20` framework) , this page is simply a gallery of thumbnail photos, when one thumbnail is selected the corresponding photo opens in full screen layout, however, when I rotate the gallery view from landscape to portrait and vice versa, the thumbnails table view correctly updates its layout according to the new orientation, but I want to make this update to be as smooth as the one in [Explore Flickr](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/explore-flickr/id372457895?mt=8) iPad app.
thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I am using [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView) to solve a similar problem.

Many consider this as the best third party grid view class out there. It's fairly easy to implement - much like how you would implement a UITableView also. I like it and it actually supports a wide range of features including what you need.

Comment: nice answer, but it does not do photos sliding animation when rotating the view, please take a look at Explore Flickr app (and try to rotate the gallery view) to see what I mean.

Comment: I saw the app and I understood what you meant. Well, GMGridView has an animated re-layout function close enough to that of Exlore Flickr's. When the size of gridview's superview changes, you can call `setNeedsLayout` and it will fix the arrangements of the objects with an animation

Comment: setNeedsLayout is used many times in GMGridView example project but it produces some kind of animation that is far away from Explore Flickr's one !!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Three20 framework so I'm not sure how well it is written etc...

However, using a `UICollectionView` will make this a lot easier.

You can still get the same layout of thumbnails (out of the box) and open them to view a full screen image and the animation of the rotation is handled really well.

It works almost exactly like a `UITableView` works so it shouldn't take too long to implement.

It's all native too.

Comment: But UICollectionView is only for iOS 6.

Comment: Correct, but there is nothing saying that iOS5 is a requirement :-)

Comment: True. I should have removed the 'but' :)